# Join 3 tables and Obtaining last update date from one table

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have a query where I am seeking results from 4 tables: Clients, Client plans,INSPLANS and CLIENTLOG 
My query pulls a lot more info from the tables but simplified looks like so:

```
select clients.name,
       insplans.desc,
       clientplans.group_no,
       convert (varchar,clientlog.FNDATE,112) as LASTUPDATEDATE,
FROM 
       PROJECT.DBO.CLIENTS
join CLIENTPLANS
       on clients.RECORD_ID = clientplans.CLIENT_ID
join INSPLANS
       on insplans.RECORD_ID = clientplans.PLAN_ID
join CLIENTLOG
       on clientlog.CLIENT_ID = clients.RECORD_ID
WHERE clients.record_id = clientplans.client_id
       and clientplans.SEQUENCE_NUM < 2
```

My problem is that when I join the `CLIENTLOG` table my results balloon from 3k which is expected to 33K with tons of duplicates.   The `clientlog` table shows an entry for every update made to the clients table.   I am just seeking to get the LAST UPDATED DATE for a record.  I know I should be using MAX by the convert function but I have a feeling that the way I have the tables joined is also incorrect.  If anyone could provide some clarification that would be awesome.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this ..

```
SELECT clients.NAME, 
       insplans.desc, 
       clientplans.group_no, 
       CONVERT (VARCHAR, clientlog.fndate, 112) AS LASTUPDATEDATE, 
FROM   project.dbo.clients 
       JOIN clientplans 
         ON clients.record_id = clientplans.client_id 
       JOIN insplans 
         ON insplans.record_id = clientplans.plan_id 
       JOIN (SELECT Max(fndate) FNDATE, 
                    client_id 
             FROM   clientlog 
             GROUP  BY clientid) CLIENTLOG 
         ON clientlog.client_id = clients.record_id 
WHERE  clients.record_id = clientplans.client_id 
       AND clientplans.sequence_num < 2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add get the latest FnDate as you said using `MAX`, you would just need to add the other columns you have selected to the `GROUP BY` clause:

```
SELECT  clients.name,
        insplans.desc,
        clientplans.group_no,
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), MAX(clientlog.FNDATE), 112) AS LASTUPDATEDATE
FROM    PROJECT.DBO.CLIENTS
        INNER JOIN CLIENTPLANS
           ON clients.RECORD_ID = clientplans.CLIENT_ID
        INNER JOIN INSPLANS
           ON insplans.RECORD_ID = clientplans.PLAN_ID
        INNER JOIN CLIENTLOG
           ON clientlog.CLIENT_ID = clients.RECORD_ID
WHERE   clientplans.SEQUENCE_NUM < 2
GROUP BY clients.name,insplans.desc, clientplans.group_no;
```

Doesn't actually make a difference here, but it is good practice to [specify a length when declaring, or converting to a VARCHAR](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length)